# How to use regular expression to match part of url in route part? WebAPI .NET core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am now trying to write a WebApi app. In route part (controller), I want to use regular expression to match part of url. However, it seems that `"/"` cannot be recognized well.

For example, the api url is `"api/books/science/list"`. I want to get `"api/books/science"` and `"list"`. I have tried the following regular expression `[HttpGet("{url=.*}/list")]`. But it seems the regular expression doesn't work. `".*"` can not match `"\"`.

The api is designed like `"api/*{path}/list"`. For `*{path}`, it may have multi structures such as `books/science` or `books/art/Asia'`. I want to use regular expression to match them and then, they can be used for the following operations.

Actually, I have tried another method to get the url `[HttpGet("{**url}")]`. But I suppose it is not a very good solution because I need to parse the url then.

Comment: It seems the required function is not suppot now [Routing enhancements](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5489#issuecomment-484834717). So sad:(

Answer (score 3):

Regex is supported through the `:regex()` parameter. See Routing in ASP.NET Core documentation on [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#regular-expressions) for information, and [Routing Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-routing-middleware) for example.

Try: `[HttpGet("{url:regex(.*)}/list")]`
As you pointed out this doesn't work because it works on the tokenized value of route url.

One alternative is to use catch-all in routing (in Startup.cs):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "therest",
    template: "/{**url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action="Index"} // Send to /home/index
);
```

Or if you know there will be limited number of path elements, you can simply include them all:

```
[HttpGet("/{url1}")]
[HttpGet("/{url1}/{url2}")]
[HttpGet("/{url1}/{url2}/{url3}")]
[HttpGet("/{url1}/{url2}/{url3}/{url4}")]
public IActionResult Test(string url1 = null, string url2 = null, string url3 = null, string url4 = null)
{
    var url = string.Join("/", url1, url2, url3, url4);
    //... return View();
}
```

The alternative I believe is to write some additional routing code in the middlelware.

Comment: Thx for your responds. ```[HttpGet("{url:regex(.*)}/list")]``` can not match ```"/"```. I mean for the example ```books/list```, YES, the regular expression can match, and ```"url"``` can get the value ```"books"```. However, if the example is ```books/science/list```, the regular expression doesn't work.

Comment: I set up thes project and tried it, seems you are right. From what I can read this is due to tokenization of route values. I can't find any simple example of bypassing that, so added a couple of suggestions on how to work around it.