# ASP.NET Core MVC route that matches any URL containing a pattern that's possibly in the middle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Typically, MVC routing is done by matching patterns from the start of the URL, e.g.:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "MyRoute", pattern: "my.io/{*suffix}", defaults: new { controller = "MyController" });
});
```

But what if I wanted to define a route that would catch *any* request that contains a certain pattern, regardless of where in the URL path it may be found? Something like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "MyRoute", pattern: "{*prefix}/my.io/{*suffix}", defaults: new { controller = "MyController" });
});
```

As you can hopefully see, I would like to catch any request that happens to include the pattern "/my.io/", regardless of whether it's at the start of URL (like it typically is), in the middle of the URL, or at the end of the URL. In all cases, I would also like to capture the prefix and suffix, if any. Needless to say, these could vary unpredictably, which is big part of the reason I want to do this using wildcards.

Is there a way to do this using MVC endpoint routing?

If yes, how would the `[Route()]` attributes on `MyController` and its methods have to be written in order to be discovered by the routing subsystem?

If no, what are my alternatives?

**UPDATE**

After some research, I determined that my problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789850/how-to-use-regular-expression-to-match-part-of-url-in-route-part-webapi-net-co). Unfortunately, there was no definitive answer there...

Comment: Pattern refers to the changing part of a URL. Area and controller names already work in any part of the URL and capture the entire content. In the default route `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"` the first part already captures the "prefix" as the controller. name, the second part captures the `action` name and the last the optional `id` parrameter. There's no need for wildcards. Have you tried specifying the route you want?

Comment: In a regular expression `.*prefix` would only match strings ending in `prefix`. Is that what you want perhaps?

Comment: This is what's probably confusing to anyone that is used to the normal way MVC routes are defined... I don't *care* what the prefix is. And neither do I care what the suffix is. I want to catch all these routes, and more: /my.io/one, /two/my.io/whatever, /something/else/my.io. Once I catch them, I want a specific controller to handle them (i.e. MyController). nowhere in the route itself is MyController required to be mentioned. That's why I pass it via defaults.

Comment: on the contrary, that *is* the normal way MVC routes are defined. The default route is `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`. This already catches every two and three-part URL. If you want to add a fixed part, you can do so. The  *real* problem with what you ask is that you want to use overlapping patterns. The default `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}` will also catch all of the patterns you propose, so you'll have to disable it. The patterns  `/{controller}/my.io/{action}` and `/{controller}/{action}/my.io` can overlap though. You can use the order of the routes to avoid this

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? This smells like an attempt to solve a *different* problem. Are you trying to specify an API version number? User or tenant name?

Comment: The reason I want this is because both prefix and suffix (whatever they may be), affect how I will process the request. The actual logic of this is very complicated and beside the point. The only routing criteria I care to fix in the pattern is the "my.io" part. Everything else is completely dynamic and cannot be tied to neither controller name nor action name. Both prefix and suffix are just path segments. They should have no meaning to the route definition. That's why I declared them as wildcards in my initial post.

Comment: On the contrary, the logic is what's important if you want an elegant solution. It's unclear why you can't just use multiple routes with that hard-coded string. If you want to change behavior, you can specify different default values for some action parameters for each route. Or you could map to a different fixed action or controller based on the location of the fixed part.

Comment: I see I'm not explaining very well, just how wildly these prefixes and suffixes can vary. It's not just 2 or 3. It's not even just 20. It's unlimited! The routes are added and changed many times a day by other people (content authors) that define URLs for things they are working on via my ASP.NET app. So you see, I can't even start to predict what and when they might need. And I certainly can't catch up by modifying my app every time someone needs to change a route for some obscure content in the database. That's why I need to define an extremely generic route and then do the rest in code.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, I discovered that perhaps @panagiotis-kanavos was pointing me in the right direction, after all!

While the prefixes and suffixes really can differ wildly (both in content and length), I realized that there still are some final limits to the lengths.

I then defined a number of routes like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Api0", pattern: "my.io", defaults: new { controller = "MyController" });
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Api1", pattern: "{part1}/my.io", defaults: new { controller = "MyController" });
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Api2", pattern: "{part1}/{part2}/my.io", defaults: new { controller = "MyController" });
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Api3", pattern: "{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/my.io", defaults: new { controller = "MyController" });
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Api4", pattern: "{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/my.io", defaults: new { controller = "MyController" });
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Api5", pattern: "{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/{part5}/my.io", defaults: new { controller = "MyController" });
    
    // ... and a couple more along the same vein.
});
```

Next, I defined multiple matching `[Route]` attributes on MyController:

```
[Route("my.io")]
[Route("{part1}/my.io")]
[Route("{part1}/{part2}/my.io")]
[Route("{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/my.io")]
[Route("{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/my.io")]
[Route("{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}/{part5}/my.io")]
...
```

This successfully handles any URL containing `my.io` that has a prefix of at most 5 levels. <strike>Naturally, this can be realistically extended up to the limit I require.</strike> **See the Important Edit below!**

Once I hit my action method, I can then simply read the entire suffix in one go like this:

```
[Route("{*suffix}")]
```

The only work I need to do in the method is stitching together all the `{partN}` segments, which I can also get straight from `Request.Url`.

### Important Edit

It would seem I spoke just a little bit too soon. As luck would have it, above solution works OK for up to 5 segment-prefixes. I did notice a slight increase in memory usage, but otherwise everything was working smoothly.

But once I added a 6-segment prefix, the app startup started to lag noticeably, and memory usage doubled to that from before.

Adding a 7-segment prefix causes my app to consume over 4 GB of memory on startup (which should be under 300 MB normally) and serving requests becomes extremely slow.

There seem to be some exponential shenanigans going on. This unfortunately means that this solution is a lot more limited than I first believed.

### Important Edit 2

After further experiments, I determined that it's not the `endpoints.MapControllerRoute()` calls that are to blame for slowness and memory-eating, but rather the `[Route]` attributes on the controller. When these rise above 5, things quickly grind to a halt. I wonder why this is?

How can I make it better?

### Important Edit 3

I've raised the issue with the ASP.NET Core team [in this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36051). We'll see where it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar requirement and it was easily solved using the ASP.NET Core Middleware **MapWhen** feature.

See the example for **MapWhen** at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline

As an example:

```
app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.HasValue && context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("my.io", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase), HandleMyIORequestsOnAllPaths);
```

and then in HandleMyIORequestsOnAllPaths

```
    private static void HandleMyIORequestsOnAllPaths(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/redirect-path");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }
```

Ensure you add app.MapWhen before app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints()

Answer (score 0):

you can apply the regex on Controller name and action name as below

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     // Regex constraint
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "regexConstraint1",
         pattern: "{controller:regex(^M.*)=MyApp}/{action:regex(^Index$|^About$)=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In this route I have applied constraint on both controller and action segment of the URL. The controller segment specifies that it should start with letter M.

The action segment specifies that the action segment should be either Index or About.
You can change regex expression as per your requirement.